# XML Views in Android

Tags: android, xml, position

I'm sorry I'm new to Android and this seems like an easy question but I just don't get it. I have two buttons (same size) and two images (different sizes). I want the buttons below the images but exactly centered to it. I searched a couple of forums but I just don't get it how that works. I also don't understand how to declare one of the images as a parent so the button could be the child.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/negativ"
    android:background="@drawable/smiley"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titlet"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="500dp" />
```

`<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textnhelpful"
        android:background="@drawable/nothelp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/negativ"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="500dp"
        />`

Comment: <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/negativ"
        android:background="@drawable/smiley"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titlet"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="500dp" />

Comment: <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textnhelpful"
        android:background="@drawable/nothelp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/negativ"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="500dp"
        />

Answer (score 0):

In android SDK you can't add image view to button as child or reverse, my solution make relative layout and add image view as child to layout make button and layout "wrap_content" and add button as child to layout andmake gravity "center".

Comment: How do I add a button as a child ?

Comment: drag n drop button in Outline Window to Layout in your outline window

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand, is there any code that I could put in the tags that classifies as a child

Answer (score 0):

Here is xml code

```
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Button" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't understand, if I use that code, then the button and imageview is just in the top left corner. I am tryingto understand how to arrange the objects in XML relatively to each other. I.E. what i am planning on doing is to use a couple of objects as a unit, so I only change the location of one object and all the others change their locations according to that